# Facebook login picture missing

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I created a Facebook application (at [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/)), it is now in live mode. I enabled facebook login, and now on the backend I fetch the following:

```
`https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email,picture&access_token=${accessToken}`
```

which returns a `picture` containing a uri that is not found (404):

```
https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?a=...
```

This is supposed to expire, but the issue is that it does not work in the first place, the uri link appears to be broken. Does anyone know why? Access token and scope permissions are all correct.